# LocalDB em visual Basic não conecta

Tags: vb.net, connectionstring, sql-server-localdb

Minha aplicação não conecta ao localDB. Já atualizei o SDT, mudei a connectionstring no App.config mas nada funciona. A parte do código em que estabeleço a conexão é essa:

```
  Dim conexao As String = "Server = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; Database = EquipamentosDB ;IntegratedSecurity=yes; Uid=auth_windows;"

  Dim reader As MySqlDataReader       

  conn = New MySqlConnection
  conn.ConnectionString = conexao

    Try
        conn.Open()

    Catch myerro As MySqlException
        MsgBox("Erro de leitura no Banco de dados:" & myerro.Message)

    End Try
```

Segui o método de configuração do localDB deste link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms233763(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Você está usando Vb6 ou Vb.net (aparentemente Vb.net)? Por favor coloque a "Exception" que está disparando.

Comment: Estou usando VB.net. Consegui resolver a pouco. Não sei ao certo oq fiz, pq alterei o Imports do MySql para o Imports System.Data.Sql e mudei para outro DB que criei ficando com a conexão assim: 
 Dim conexao As String = "Server = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = Equipamentos ; Integrated Security=yes; Uid=auth_windows;"
Alterei os comandos todos para apenas SqlDataReader e SqlConnection. Magicamente funcionou. Muito obrigado!